# Retrieving Data Depending on the Username

Tags: c#, linq, asp.net-mvc-4, lambda

I am doing Authentication depending on the username.So an unauthorized person can't see any methods which is working fine.

> The problem is all of the users are able to each others data.
>   Person A shouldn't see the records of person B so that he/she can't edit another person's records.**Does anyone know how I can write a lambda expression for that?**
>   I have my Edit method pasted below:

```
// GET: /IcerikDB_/Edit/5
[Authorize(Roles = "Administrator")]
public ActionResult Edit(int id)
{
    icerik icerik = db.icerik.Find(id);
    ViewBag.Kategorid = new SelectList(db.Kategoriler, "Id", "Adi", icerik.Kategorid);
    ViewBag.Userid = new SelectList(db.Users, "UserId", "UserName", icerik.Userid);
    return View(icerik);
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Edit(icerik icerik)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        if (User != null && User.Identity != null && User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            string userName = User.Identity.Name;
            var user = db.Users.First(u => u.UserName == userName);
            icerik.Userid = user.UserId;
            db.Entry(icerik).State = EntityState.Modified;
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
    }
    ViewBag.Kategorid = new SelectList(db.Kategoriler, "Id", "Adi", icerik.Kategorid);
    ViewBag.Userid = new SelectList(db.Users, "UserId", "UserName", icerik.Userid);
    return View(icerik);
}
```

**Here is the code for icerik.cs**

```
namespace KategoriEditor.Icerik_DB
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

    public partial class icerik
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> Kategorid { get; set; }
        public Nullable<System.Guid> Userid { get; set; }
        [DataType(DataType.Date)]
        public Nullable<System.DateTime> Baslangic { get; set; }
        [DataType(DataType.Date)]
        public Nullable<System.DateTime> Bitis { get; set; }
        public string tamicerik { get; set; }
        public string kisaicerik { get; set; }
        public string resimlink { get; set; }

        public virtual Kategoriler Kategoriler { get; set; }
        public virtual Users Users { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why are you checking User.Identity in ActionResult, use Authorize attribute or custom and define it in one place. Every entity is owned by some person (id), display only the entites of that person. When editing check if person who is editing also created the entity.

Comment: That part of the code is to insert UserName when the user clicks **"Save"** button. **[Authorize]** is written at the beginning of the controller to take care of Authorization. What I want my code to do is to show only the records of the logged in user.

Comment: I'm not seeing anything grabbing logs for the model...  I see a model passed in, is converted to a select list, and returned with a view.

Comment: Actually I need to filter that and show only the records of the **"logged in"** user.

Comment: I updated my question and pasted "get" method of the **ActionResult "edit"** too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
public ActionResult Edit(int id)
{
    // Get the currently logged in user.
    string userName = User.Identity.Name;
    var user = db.Users.First(u => u.UserName == userName);

    // Determine whether the requested id is the same id as the currently logged in user.
    icerik icerik = db.icerik.Find(id);
    if (icerik.Userid.HasValue && icerik.Userid.Value == user.UserId)
    {       
        ViewBag.Kategorid = new SelectList(db.Kategoriler, "Id", "Adi", icerik.Kategorid);

        // You should not need this SelectList anymore.
        //ViewBag.Userid = new SelectList(db.Users, "UserId", "UserName", icerik.Userid);
        return View(icerik);
    }
    // This redirect the unauthorized user to the homepage. This can be any other page of course.
    return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home"); 
}
```

Comment: It gave me and error saying that Operator "==" cannot be applied to operands XXXController.cs of type 'int' and 'System.Guid'
The error is right on:
`if (id == user.UserId)`

Comment: @RuhiGoktas can you show the code for the `icerik` class, and describe that it actually is?

Comment: I updated the question and pasted the icerik.cs there

Comment: Alright works fine.But when Person A tries editing for person B I get an error:
** "There is no ViewData item of type 'IEnumerable <SelectListItem>' that has the key 'Kategorid'**.
Can we write something like "try &catch block"?

Comment: @RuhiGoktas you should redirect Person A back to another page. The homepage or something. They should not be on the page. I'll update my answer with an example.

Comment: Perfect!That's exactly what I was looking for :)
Thanks @Henk Mollema